# MySQL - reducing number of SELECTs with one smart WHERE

Tags: mysql

I have a table with 3 columns that keeps some four-digit `ids` in it. Like that:

```
+ main_id + id_1 + id_2 + id_3 +
|---------|------|------|------|
|    1    | 1000 | 1500 | 1900 |
|    2    | 1001 | 1501 | 1901 |
|    3    | 1002 | 1502 | 1902 |
+---------+------+------+------+
```

The idea is the values can't repeat themselves via other combinations. I mean, if the table already has `1001 - 1501 - 1901`, combinations like `1001 - 1901 - 1501` or `1501 - 1001 - 1901` can't appear in the table anymore and should point the initial combination with `main_id` and should return `2` in any case.

For this, I got a stored function to which I pass all three `ids` and get the `main_id` on exit, like this one:

```
SET temp_id = (SELECT `main_id` FROM `tableName` WHERE (`id_1` = id1 AND `id_2` = id2 AND `id_3` = id3) LIMIT 1);

IF (temp_id IS NULL) THEN SET temp_id = (SELECT `main_id` FROM `tableName` WHERE (`id_1` = id1 AND `id_2` = id3 AND `id_3` = id2) LIMIT 1);
    IF(temp_id IS NULL) THEN SET temp_id = (SELECT `main_id` FROM `tableName` WHERE (`id_1` = id2 AND `id_2` = id1 AND `id_3` = id3) LIMIT 1);
        IF(temp_id IS NULL) THEN SET temp_id = (SELECT `main_id` FROM `tableName` WHERE (`id_1` = id2 AND `id_2` = id3 AND `id_3` = id1) LIMIT 1);
            IF(temp_id IS NULL) THEN SET temp_id = (SELECT `main_id` FROM `tableName` WHERE (`id_1` = id3 AND `id_2` = id1 AND `id_3` = id2) LIMIT 1);
                IF(temp_id IS NULL) THEN SET temp_id = (SELECT `main_id` FROM `tableName` WHERE (`id_1` = id3 AND `id_2` = id2 AND `id_3` = id1) LIMIT 1);
                END IF;
            END IF;
        END IF;
    END IF;
END IF;

RETURN temp_id;
```

I thought about using all of possible combinations in `WHERE` clauses in one `SELECT` with `OR` operator, like this one:

```
SELECT `main_id` FROM `tableName`
  WHERE (((`id_1` = id1 AND `id_2` = id2 AND `id_3` = id3)
    OR (`id_1` = id2 AND `id_2` = id1 AND `id_3` - id3)
    ...
    )) LIMIT 1
```

but it would run through all possible solutions not stopping when one found. The previous example would at least stop going deeper if the combination is found.

For only three columns I get 6 combinations in total. I plan to do the same thing for 4 and 5 columns, giving me a *huge* amount of select queries in total.

The question is, is there a way to speed this function up? Reduce the amount of `SELECT` queries I send? I use InnoDB, maybe something quicker would come in handy?

**UPDATE**

I need to pull out one main id for a set of three values. So far, the endless `if` statements are the fastest solution. And I'm looking for an optimization.

Comment: @Strawberry there could could be more than 3 columns, no problem with that. And the order is not important.

Comment: One way to do it is to construct a single-column table from the vales you are looking for (you can use a union), then select the ID where all the columns exist in that table

Comment: @Strawberry There will be a maximum of 5 in the nearest future

Comment: If the order is unimportant then surely the solution is to store the values from lowest to highest (exactly as your example).

Comment: @Strawberry I need to pull out one `main_id` for a set of three values. So far, the endless `if` statements are the fastest solution. And I'm looking for an optimization.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest concatenating the ids together to form a unique representation, and then using that to remove duplicates:

```
select t.*, m.cnt as NumDups
from (select min(main_id) as main_id, count(*) as cnt
             concat(least(id_1, id_2, id_3),
                    (id_1 + id_2 + id_3) - least(id_1, id_2, id_3) - greatest(id_1, id_2, id_3),
                    greatest(id_1, id_2, id_3)
                   ) as ids
      from tablename t
      group by ids
     ) m join
     tablename t
     on m.main_id = t.main_id;
```

EDIT:

If you are looking for one match and the variables `@id1`, `@id2`, and `@id3` contain the values, then you can do:

```
select t.*
from tablename t
where least(@id1, @id2, @id3) = least(id_1, id_2, id_3) and
      ((@id1 + @id2 + @id3 - least(@id1, @id2, @id3) - greatest(@id1, @id2, @id3)) =
       (id_1 + id_2 + id_3) - least(id_1, id_2, id_3) - greatest(id_1, id_2, id_3)
      ) and
      greatest(@id1, @id2, @id3) = greatest(id_1, id_2, id_3);
```

Comment: It seems like this would be cumbersome for any more than 3 columns

Comment: @Strawberry . . . Perhaps, but this query is quite explicitly about 3 columns.

Comment: Um, comments and statements like 'I plan to do the same thing for 4 and 5 columns' don't count? Still, I'm not saying I have a better idea - because I don't!!

Comment: Sorry, but this really looks like crutch-driven development solution. I have a feeling (and the tests showed this) my pokecode would evolve into slowpokecode.

Comment: @Nordenheim . . . Are you saying this is slower than your current approach?  And, are you looking for one match or to get a reduced set of values for the entire table?

Comment: @GordonLinoff seems like it, one match

Answer (score 0):

SQL Fiddle appears to be unstable right now but here's a simple example demonstrating the technique in my comment.

Suppose you are looking for the main_id that corresponds to the values 1002, 1502 and 1902:

```
select main_id
from ids main
where exists (select 1 from ids where main.main_id = ids.main_id and id_1 in (select 1502 union select 1002 union select 1902))
and exists (select 1 from ids where main.main_id = ids.main_id and id_2 in (select 1502 union select 1002 union select 1902))
and exists (select 1 from ids where main.main_id = ids.main_id and id_3 in (select 1502 union select 1002 union select 1902))
```

In your case you would refactor this into your stored procedure and use a temporary table to store your input values instead of the union.

Answer (score 0):

Normalize you original table using union, then you could solve this problem by trivial SQL.

```
select main_id,group_concat(id)
from 
    (
    select main_id,id_1 as id from tablename
    union all
    select main_id,id_2 as id from tablename
    union all
    select main_id,id_3 as id from tablename
    ) as ids
where
    id in (1001,1501,1901)
group by
    main_id
having count(*) = 3
```